# How best to route dynamic and static routes in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a small-ish project I'm working on and I want to be able to have routes like this work at the same time.

```
indexRouter.get('/section/:path*', sectionController.pathLogic);
indexRouter.get('/section/about', staticController.about);
```

Currently, the * in /section/:path* catches everything and /section/about is ignored.

Is there a way to handle both of these routes at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that you define the routes matters, so always put general routes last when you define them. The router traverses down through the tree of routes and if it finds the possible route it stops there (unless it's middleware and calls `next()`). So in your case, the route with '*' is more general, so the router stops there.

Comment: Thanks @Knownasilya, I should probably RTFM, my routes were in the wrong order this solves that problem.